# Salesforce Getting organization online users

Tags: administration, user-management

Can anybody help me how to get logged in online users into my salesforce organization

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after? You mean you want a list of users currently logged in?

Comment: Yes Lacey that is exactly what i want @LaceySnr

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be part of the spring 14 (api 30) release under :

```
Setup > Security Controls > Session Management
```

[image: salesforce UI User session information]

I'm not sure what actions result in a row in this page,the testmanange your see in the screenshot just performed a login and verfication code authentication.